# Why does my .exe file run on my computer but not my friends? using python and pyinstaller

Tags: python, tkinter, exe, pyinstaller, fatal-error

I have made a small app and have used pyinstaller to make an .exe file which works fine on my end but not on my friends computer and gives a "Fatal Error Detected: Failed to execute script japanese_app_visua" message. We are both using windows 10.

I used tkinter, could this be the problem?

This was the command:

```
 pyinstaller.exe --onefile  --windowed --icon=icons/app_icon.ico japanese_app_visual.py
```

This was the message log:

```
$ pyinstaller.exe --onefile  --windowed --icon=icons/app_icon.ico japanese_app_visual.py
71 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.6
71 INFO: Python: 3.8.1
71 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0
72 INFO: wrote C:\Users\Kev\Desktop\Programming Portfolio\Japanese\japanese_app_visual.spec
74 INFO: UPX is not available.
82 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\Kev\\Desktop\\Programming Portfolio\\Japanese',
 'C:\\Users\\Kev\\Desktop\\Programming Portfolio\\Japanese']
82 INFO: checking Analysis
82 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
82 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
84 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
91 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
2655 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
2656 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'c:\\users\\kev\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib'
4021 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
4115 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
4129 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\kev\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe
4196 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\Kev\Desktop\Programming Portfolio\Japanese\japanese_app_visual.py
4233 INFO: Processing module hooks...
4233 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
4235 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
4304 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-lib2to3.py"...
4308 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
4309 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sysconfig.py"...
4309 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py"...
4310 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
4352 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-_tkinter.py"...
4484 INFO: checking Tree
4484 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
4484 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
4537 INFO: checking Tree
4537 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
4537 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
4567 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
4592 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
4595 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
4597 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
4602 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
4871 INFO: Looking for eggs
4871 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\kev\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python38.dll
4871 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
4874 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\Kev\Desktop\Programming Portfolio\Japanese\build\japanese_app_visual\warn-japanese_app_visual.txt
4914 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\Kev\Desktop\Programming Portfolio\Japanese\build\japanese_app_visual\xref-japanese_app_visual.html
4947 INFO: checking PYZ
4947 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
4947 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\Kev\Desktop\Programming Portfolio\Japanese\build\japanese_app_visual\PYZ-00.pyz
5461 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\Kev\Desktop\Programming Portfolio\Japanese\build\japanese_app_visual\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
5472 INFO: checking PKG
5472 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
5472 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
7624 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
7647 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\kev\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\runw.exe
7647 INFO: checking EXE
7647 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
7647 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
7717 INFO: Copying icons from ['icons\\app_icon.ico']
7762 INFO: Writing RT_GROUP_ICON 0 resource with 76 bytes
7763 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 1 resource with 1128 bytes
7763 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 2 resource with 2440 bytes
7763 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 3 resource with 4264 bytes
7763 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 4 resource with 9640 bytes
7763 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 5 resource with 8031 bytes
7765 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\Kev\Desktop\Programming Portfolio\Japanese\build\japanese_app_visual\runw.exe.p7lx1xhk
7812 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 1 language 0
7813 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\Kev\Desktop\Programming Portfolio\Japanese\dist\japanese_app_visual.exe
7870 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

---

I got it working using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60953781/12470649)

Comment: Why did you hide parts of the error message from us?

Comment: I didn't ... I copied from the console

Comment: It's literally `"Fatal Error Detected: Failed to execute .."` including the ".."?

Comment: ah sorry! it was a window that popped up with the title Fatal Error Detected and the message says Failed to execute script japanese_app_visual

Comment: has it been compiled on your computer? will your friend be able to run it if he/she compiled it on theri computer?

Comment: I dont know to be honest, I thought pyinstaller compiled it. My friend doesn't have any IDE or python installed

Comment: I found this about tkinter: 'It is usually a shared library (or DLL)'. If so you could be right and it could be the problem if the dll is not present.

Comment: the tkinter dll?

Comment: @KevinNisbet build without `--windowed` and get your friend to run the executable from a command prompt. Then we'll get the traceback.

Comment: Ok, so the error message says, `_tkinter.tclError: couldnt open "exit.png": no such file or directory. [2944] failed to execute script jappanese_app` So I presume i need to add the data files but how?